# Annoying Ilustrator feature since I started using it [AI CS6]

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

I have already searched how to disable this... "feature". I have no idea whats the actual name of... this, so I just uploaded a gif so you guys can see what I'm talking about.

[image]

Every time when I'm using the pen and when the mouse gets closer to the workplace border it automatically moves. Most of the times this annoys the hell out of me.

Anyone knows if you can disable it or change its sensivity?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can be disabled or modified. If I think my path is going to go beyond the window I press and hold `spacebar` to move my window around without losing the ability to add on to my pen path. Releasing `spacebar` will cause the pen tool to come back.